# Getting different output for different positioning of my print statement in python 3

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

#### This is the normal code i was writing and this code has the desired output i wanted

```
a = [1,1,2,3,5,8,4,13,21,34,55,89]
less5num = []
for i in a:
    if i < 5:
        less5num.append(i)
        less5num.sort()
print(less5num)

Output
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

#### now, if i keep print inside the if loop i get a number pyramid

```
a = [1,1,2,3,5,8,4,13,21,34,55,89]
less5num = []
for i in a:
    if i<5:
        less5num.append(i)
        less5num.sort()
        print(less5num)

Output
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

#### if i keep print out of the if loop i get a recursive number pyramid

```
a = [1,1,2,3,5,8,4,13,21,34,55,89]
less5num = []
for i in a:
    if i<5:
        less5num.append(i)
        less5num.sort()
    print(less5num)

Output
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

## why is this hapenning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first block of code, the print is not inside the `for` loop, it is executed after *all* the elements are iterated, only the numbers less than 5 are added to list and sorted.

In your second block of code, the print is inside the `loop`, and also only executes *if* number is *less than 5*, so only less number of times print is executed.

In your 3rd block of code, your print is in the `for loop`, but not within the `if` block, so when every element is encountered, a printing happens, so as many number of times as there are numbers in your list.

Answer (score 1):

```py
a = [1,1,2,3,5,8,4,13,21,34,55,89]
less5num = []
for i in a:
    if i<5:
        less5num.append(i)
        less5num.sort()
    # this print in loop but outside if statement
    print(less5num)
```

Your print is in loop but outside if statement. That's why all iterations are print in console

Answer (score 0):

If the `print` is outside the loop, it prints the list once with all numbers less than 5.

If it's inside the `if` you print the list once for every time you find a number less than 5. The list is mid creation so it grows larger.

If it's inside the loop, you print it once for every number in the loop.

You can visualize it using [pythontutor](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a%20%3D%20%5B1,1,2,3,5,8,4,13,21,34,55,89%5D%0Aless5num%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0Afor%20i%20in%20a%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20i%3C5%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20less5num.append%28i%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20less5num.sort%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28less5num%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false).

Comment: Thanks for the website its really intuitive!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

### In the first example:

There are 5 elements in list that are less than 5 so you print it 5 times.

```
[1,1,2,3,4]
```

### In the second example:

The list is printed after all values in the list. Since there are 12 elements in the list you print it 12 times.

```
[1,1,2,3,5,8,4,13,21,34,55,89]
```